# ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver API Manager 3 wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I use Api Manager 3.0.0 wso2 in docker and key manager 5.8
and config them but when api manager starting get this error

```
[2021-01-10 09:42:48,993] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
[2021-01-10 09:42:48,994] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:931) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
```

how can i resolve this problem?

port 9611 and 9711 are open in server!

Comment: Could you please share the full error stack?

Comment: the full error stack is given below

Answer (score 0):

this is full stack error

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/java/openjdk,
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-3.0.0,
Using Java memory options: -Xms4096m -Xmx6144m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g,
andes [org.wso2.andes.wso2.internal.QpidBundleActivator] INFO : Setting BundleContext in PluginManager,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,169]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,185]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.15.0-74-generic, amd64,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,185]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /opt/java/openjdk/jre,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,186]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_222,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,186]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.222-b10,AdoptOpenJDK,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,186]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-3.0.0,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,187]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-3.0.0/tmp,
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,187]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : wso2carbon, en-US, 
[2021-01-13 11:21:41,363]  INFO - DefaultCryptoProviderComponent 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.,
[2021-01-13 11:21:42,114]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service,
[2021-01-13 11:21:42,337]  INFO - TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service,
[2021-01-13 11:21:44,864]  WARN - Digester Match [Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig] failed to set property [sslEnabledProtocols] to [TLSv1.2],
[2021-01-13 11:21:45,844]  INFO - ConsentManagerComponent ConsentManagerComponent is activated.,
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,103]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9611,
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,104]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9711,
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,175]  INFO - DataBridgeDS Successfully deployed Agent Server ,
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,278] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,296] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:931) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,082]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 126ms,
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,111]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Connected to mount at configregistry in 6ms,
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,112]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Connected to mount at govregistry in 7ms,
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,232]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Connected to mount at configregistry in 1ms,
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,233]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Connected to mount at govregistry in 2ms,
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,252]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE,
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,279] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
[2021-01-13 11:21:47,284] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:931) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
```

This block is constantly repeated

```
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,278] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
[2021-01-13 11:21:46,296] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. ,
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset,
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:931) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_222],
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:212) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary_5.2.12.jar:?],
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222],
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222],
```

Thanks for your attention.